# How do I set parent height/width to height/width of editable span-child?

Tags: css, contenteditable, html

I have a div that has a child which is an editable span.

Now obviously, the size of an editable span constantly changes.

Therefore, how can I set the div's height and width to be the same as that of the span, every time the size of the span changes (hopefully without the use of javascript) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/4k87M/1/

CSS

```
#div-parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
#span-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div-parent">
    <span id="span-child" contenteditable>This is editable</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the parent `div` to adapt it's height and width to the child `span` you can do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4k87M/3/)**

css:

```
#span-child {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

**EDIT after [Hashem Qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami)'s comment**

Span is an inline element and doesn't need `height` or `width` decleration see this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4k87M/5/)**

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't removing position, top & left when I tried your suggestion so it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element. `width`/`height` property is not applicable to inline elements. These **have no effect** in your case. You can safely remove them and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `position: absolute` from the span element then it would work fine

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/4k87M/4/

```
#span-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```